# I can't stop coming up with Riley's

Tags: riddle, wordplay

My Prefix comes from a tree and gets salty.

My Infix is a length of time usually equivalent to 4 years.

My Suffix is what you are using right now.

My whole is a game, a TV show, and a noun.

Comment: Is the infix, $marriage$? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are

> MASTERMIND.

My Prefix comes from a tree and gets salty.

> MAST means the nuts of forest trees -- though usually in the context of having them eaten by animals, where they usually wouldn't be salted. Pugmonkey has a better explanation in comments: this is about the MAST of a ship, which of course gets salty because of seawater.

My Infix is a length of time usually equivalent to 4 years.

> In many places a politician's or government's TERM of office is four years.

My Suffix is what you are using right now.

> It's hard to solve a puzzle without making at least some use of one's MIND.

My whole is a game, a TV show, and a noun.

> Pattern-guessing game; UK quiz show; and of course a noun.

Comment: I think the prefix is actually referring to the rot13(znfg bs n fuvc).

Comment: Well done! Although the prefix refers to what @Pugmonkey mentioned, if you change your answer to this then I'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense than my interpretation. Will adjust. [EDITED to add:] Done now.